# AS3: Child added, but not displaying

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, addchild

```
public class ItemView extends MovieClip {

  private var _title:TextField;
  private var _extra:MovieClip;

  public function ItemView( ) {
    setup();
    return;
  }

  private function setup( ):void {
    trace("ItemView::setup()");
    _title = new TextField();
    _title.text = "Title";
    addChild(_title);
    _extra = new MovieClip();
    _extra.width = 200;
    _extra.height = 40;
    _extra.graphics.beginFill(0x0000ff);
    _extra.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    _extra.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(_extra);
    return;
  }

}
```

When I create an instance of `ItemView` and add it to the stage, "Title" displays but the blue square does not. However, if I make the `graphics` calls on `this` instead of `_extra`, I do see the blue square. This tells me that _extra itself is not displaying properly, but I can't figure out why.

What am I missing? Is there some special procedure for adding one `MovieClip` to another?

Comment: I'm not sure this solves anything, but you should pretty much never use MovieClip outside of the IDE. Use the Sprite class instead. MovieClip has a lot of useless overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little quirk.

When you set the width/height of the MovieClip object, Flash internally also adjusts the `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties. For instance, if the original width was 100, and now you've set it to 200, then the new `scaleX` should be 2. This means Flash will display it at 2X scale horizontally.

Now, initially the width is 0 (blank object), so when you set a new width, the new `scaleX` should become infinite - or 0, as Flash does it.

So even though you've drawn something onto the object, it's still at zero scale, which is why nothing gets displayed. The way to remedy this, as suggested by another poster, is to avoid setting width/height on the blank object or alternatively to reset `scaleX` and `scaleY` to 1 after your drawing is done.

```
...
_extra.graphics.endFill();
_extra.scaleX = _extra.scaleY = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete

```
_extra.width = 200;
_extra.height = 40;
```

Comment: Huh? Why... How was this the cause? How could setting heights and widths possibly have this effect?

Comment: "Except for TextField and Video objects, a display object with no content (such as an empty sprite) has a width of 0, even if you try to set width to a different value."

Comment: @Chris so just to point out. After you've drawn your rect you can adjust width and height as you like.